# Распределение и удаление памяти

Tags: c, массивы

Дело обстоит так. Задал препод задание. В котором надо - распределить память под элементы массива и потом освободить память. 
Сделал задание.

```
typedef struct
{
    int Id;
    char FIO[NAME_SIZE];
    int Mark;
    char Teacher[NAME_SIZE];
}Student;

Student students[100];
```

Считаю, что последней строкой я распределяю память на 100 элементов. Но! Я начал читать про последовательности, нашёл какой-то:

> Init – начальное распределение памяти
> под элементы последовательности;

И вот вопрос. Даже два. Надо ли мне делать распределение памяти через init(препод в отпуске, так что уже поздно метаться, тут если правильно через init делать, значит надо делать)? И второй - где прочитать про это. Слегка прогуглил операцию init, о неё кроме как в методичке моей - ничего нету.
Помогите плз!

УТОЧНЕНИЕ описана функция Init:

```
int Init(SEQ* seq, int MaxSize)
{
    if (seq->pArr != NULL)
        return -1;
    seq->pArr = (int*) malloc(MaxSize*sizeof(int));
    if (seq->pArr == NULL)
        return -2;
    seq->nMaxSize = MaxSize;
    seq->nSize = 0;

    return MaxSize;
}
```

Comment: Последовательности? Что бы это значило? О каких последовательностях идёт речь и что такое Init?

Comment: "Для реализации динамического массива, который в литературе еще называется последовательностью, необходимо обеспечить реализацию операций добавления и удаления его отдельных элементов."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Операции init в C/C++ нет. Равно как и функции такой. Возможно подразумевалось, что в случае написания собственных классов нужно отдельно конструировать объект, а отдельно вызывать ф-цию задающую его начальное состояние. Но тогда она может иметь любое разумное имя, лишь бы была четкая документация как этот класс использовать, но я считаю это неудачным решением, т.к. обычно в конструкторе можно сразу сделать объект полноценным и готовым к эксплуатации.

Если речь идет в задании про распределение и удаление памяти, то следует обратить внимание на работу с динамической памятью (heap или куча). В C для этого используется пара ф-ций malloc/free, в C++ лучше использовать операторы new и delete. И тогда получается, что в методичке хотят, чтобы Вы просто разбили свою программу на ф-ции, одна из которых будет создавать Ваш массив, а другая - удалять. Ну, это помимо самой работы =)

Comment: Может, вы и правы. В методичке была указана операция Init, как будто, это слово уже зарезервировано... И далее был код с примером, в нём вначале объявлялась функция Init(), а потом описывалась такая штука (см. вопрос). Я в кодах не силён. Получается Init - это пользовательская функция? Слово не зарезервировано?

Comment: Начал читать) О, да! Это то, что надо по спискам! спасибо!) Только это вроде не решает вопроса с выделением памяти и освобождением памяти.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить что вам нужно реализовать список(опираясь на личный опыт студента). Если это так, то вам [сюда](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/cpp/dlist.php)

Comment: да, списки тоже где-то звучали, вопрос в том, что если можно реализовать без них, если си меня, вообще как язык не интересует, то можно ли без них делать всё? В задании про списки ничего не сказано, в комментах к лабам тоже тишина про списки.
Уточнил, даже в кр не указано, что надо списками делать...Сортировки, двумерные массивы, пользовательские функции...Ничего про списки. Жить без них можно?

Comment: можно, Student students[100], в данном случае students[i] - это элемент списка

Comment: понял! только что понял) Если ещё в комментах скажите, что Student students[100] - это и есть распределение памяти, и напишите, как её(память) отчистить - тогда закрываем вопрос!

Comment: читайте внимательно вторую часть ответа gecube, по-моему иссчерпывающе )